reference sphinx |version| as monospace and no leading spaces
I'm trying to reference the sphinx |version| in a monospace block (and no spaces around it) in my .rst file like this...
You can install foo_project library with:

``pip install -U foo_project==|version|``

Cross-references with |version| outside a monospace block work just fine, but how do I make that version number show up inline with a monospaced font?
Also if I want to reference that |version| in a string like this, how do I get |version| interpolated?  My use-case is:
git+https://github.com/foo_username/foo_project.git@|version|

As my rst code currently stands, |version| has to have spaces around it for it to be recognized.  What should I do to fix this problem?

Nested inline markup is notoriously difficult or impossible in reStructuredText. I think you can introduce an empty space escaped by a backslash placed just before like this: git+https://github.com/foo_username/foo_project.git@\ |version|. But then, I do not know how to format this whole thing as code sample (in between pairs of backquotes).

Nested inline markup is notoriously difficult (or impossible) in reStructuredText.
You could come up with something along the lines of the following...
In Sphinx's configuration file conf.py:
from foo_project.__about__ import __version__

project = "foo_project"

version = f"{__version__}"

rst_prolog = f"""
.. |code_project| replace:: ``{project}``
.. |code_version| replace:: ``{version}``
.. |pip_cmd| replace:: ``pip install -U {project}=={version}``
.. |pip_git_cmd| replace:: ``pip install git+https://github.com/foo_username/{project}.git@{version}``
"""

And in a Sphinx reStructuredText document:
You can install the |code_project| library in its version |code_version| with one of the following commands:

* |pip_cmd|

* |pip_git_cmd|

References:

Read the documentation for Sphinx's rst_prolog: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-rst_prolog
See this related question: Composing roles in reStructuredText; and maybe consider this potentially useful helper library: https://sphinx.silverrainz.me/comboroles/examples.html#nested-parse.


unfortunately .. |version| replace:: ... defeats the whole purpose of the exercise.  I am dyniamically importing my version number into sphinx from my __about__.py file, which has __version__ defined in it.  I am using |version| so I can get the version number dynamically... a static mapping in rst is what I had before I started using |version|.

Right, I see... Maybe this newer version of the answer is more helpful. But in any case, I do not believe there is a particularly good solution, they will all be somewhat awkward.

Your edit looks tolerable... I'll try it and accept if it works out
